# Workpath for Tiled GeoTIFF Warp and Worldfile

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gdalwarp, batch

I am attempting to identify a workpath (or script) for warping TIFFs (and TFWs) and saving them out.
Have tried diff methods "batch mode" and pointed it to the relevant folder etc. But I just get an error message.[image] See pic attached.

Is there any settings that are incorrect? Or a script I could run that does the whole routine?

JPEG with JGW is the ideal output. But not essential, where warping is.

Comment: Almost always, the error message tells you the error. It is critical information to include when asking someone else for help.

Comment: We should really know what the error message says.